# javascript looking for value before PHP variable is read in

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a site wide currency exchange thing on my website and I a salary row in MySQL and I use PHP to print that on the page, now my question is if there's a way/how to get the value of that PHP variable and use it in my javascript functions.

I had the same problem before with something else but I worked around it.

```
var currencyRates = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=' + access_key,   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {

        setUSD = function() {
            var USDrate = json.rates.USD;
            console.log("Setting site currency to USD ($)");
            console.log(USDrate);
            var USDsalary;
            document.getElementById('salarySpan').innerHTML = USDsalary;
            console.log(USDsalary);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<b>Yearly Salary <span id='currencySign'>$</span>:</b> <span id='salarySpan'>".$_SESSION['lon']."</span><br>
```

I get this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined
    at setUSD (script.js:206)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (profile.php:67)

I understand it to be the javascript looking for a value in the span before the PHP value is actually there, so my question is if there's a way to fix that?

Comment: Where is `USDsalary` coming from?

Comment: You need to take care to only start executing your JS code once the whole page has been loaded and rendered by the client. You can use client side events for that. So something like `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);` or similar. You will find loads of examples on the internet.

Comment: @Connum I made a mistake there didn't I? I was thinking the value of the salarySpan would become USDsalary but it goes the other way doesn't it?

Comment: The problem is rather that `USDsalary` is not defined anywhere. Also, you can't set a `.value` on a `<span>` element, you're probably looking for `.innerText` or `.innerHTML`

Comment: Also, you're just setting `setUSD` to a reference to the anonymous function, but the function is never called?

Comment: @Connum Yeah I meant to put .innerHTML, I also have a button calling the setUSD  <button id='buttonCurrency' onclick='setUSD()'>USD ($)</button>

Comment: Where is `USDsalary` coming from? You should also be starting all the JS code execution when page is ready.

Comment: @ShababbKarim Yeah that's the problem right? I'm just not sure how to do that properly

Comment: @ThomasSandelin, I have added an answer. Please check if the error still exists.

Comment: Unless you have the `setUSD`variable defined outside, in the global scope, you won't be able to call `setUSD()` from a button click, since the variable will only exist in the success-functions scope.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap all JS code inside the `Jquery.ready` function. Shorthand for `Jquery.ready` is wrapping inside `$` function.

```
$(function() {

    var currencyRates = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=' + access_key,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {

            setUSD = function() {
                var USDrate = json.rates.USD;
                console.log("Setting site currency to USD ($)");
                console.log(USDrate);
                document.getElementById('salarySpan').innerHTML = USDsalary;
                console.log(USDsalary);
            }
        }
    });
```

})

Comment: It did something, but still doesn't work. Now I just get undefined instead of "Cannot get propery of null"

Comment: Has the error message changed? Can you try doing something like `$('span#salarySpan').html(USDsalary)` ? The value returning from `document.getElementById('salarySpan')` is `null` in your code.

Comment: See that's the problem. The value is `null` because the PHP isnt loaded in yet, I think?

Comment: No I don't think so because once you wrap all your javascript inside the jquery `$` function you are basically saying that **execute this lines of code only when the whole page is loaded**. So that is not a problem anymore. Can you do one thing? Comment out all the code inside the `success` function. Let the page load and then go to the browser console. Then write `document.getElementById('salarySpan')`. Does it give undefined in the console?

Comment: of course, no I don't get anything in the console then

Comment: Actually I did `var abc = document.getElementById('salarySpan').innerHTML;
        console.log(abc);` and I got "540000" (the correct number) in the console, so now I'm officially lost

Comment: Is this all the Javascript you have in your page? I am unsure now where the problem lies right now.

Comment: Not the only thing, but the rest shouldn't matter. I mean I got the correct number from the salary field now so wouldn't I just take it and multiply with exchange rates and then put it back in the field?

Comment: Yes that should do. You probably are getting the error from somewhere else because to me it seems like the code inside is working fine. If you need a more in depth help then I can create a chat room.

Comment: I actually have one more question that might need some "discussion" so  if you would like that'd be awesome